# SQL ignoring string in where condition

Tags: mysql

Why if I run a query with gibberish at the end of the where condition it incorrectly returns a result.
Example:

```
SELECT * FROM contractor_table WHERE contractorID = '97sd'
```

I am getting the row with the ID 97, when I should get no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here is that you are comparing the `contractorID` column, which is integer or some other numeric type, against a string literal `97sd`.  This doesn't make any sense, so MySQL, based on its casting rules, attempts to first cast `97sd` to an integer.  Consider the result of the following query:

```
SELECT CAST('97sd' AS unsigned);
```

In fact, this outputs just `97`, the integer.  So, in practice this means that the "gibberish" at the end of your string literal, which begins with an integer, will be ignored by MySQL.

But best practice here is to always compare columns against the correct literal types.  So use the following version always, for best results:

```
SELECT * FROM contractor_table WHERE contractorID = 97;
```

Comment: Ok, I feel like that's incorrect behaviour for MySQL. How do stop MySQL from ignoring it?

Comment: Don't compare numeric columns to strings.  In most other databases, your code would not even compile.  This is the root cause of the problem.

Comment: What if you can't help it? The code running the query may not know whether the column is a string or number

Comment: It is not the code's responsibility to use best practice, but rather it is up to the _author_ of that code.  It is not MySQL's job to police your code in the first place.

Comment: What about when you've taken over a project that has 100's of queries that "incorrectly" operate like this, it is impractical to go over and add a test in the code to check for the correct variable type

Comment: There is no easy fix for that problem, but then again it is not really MySQL's problem.  Take this as a lesson to write better SQL code, and move on.

Comment: I really feel like this is a bug in MySQL, it shouldn't be assuming that because I gave it a string with an int that I wanted to to filter out the string, unless I tell it to. It's doing something I haven't asked it to do

Comment: Yes, _but_ you shouldn't even be comparing a numeric column against text in the first place.  That mistake is on the engineer who wrote that code.  One exception: At some point the `contractor_table` column was actually text, then later changed to numeric.  At that point, the query still ran, so no one noticed this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happends when you have column type int or other numeric if you convert it into varchar than it will retun no output

Comment: But the OP's query is actually returning an output :-)